# How to return single object from relation subquery Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am learning `Laravel`

I need to return only `1 raw from relation subquery` instead of an `array` with `1` element

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
    public function changeMembership(Users $user, Memberships $membership)
{
    $user->load([
        'transactions' => function ($q) {
            $q->where('status', 'approved')->latest()->first();
        },
        'latest_membership',
        'billing'
    ]);

    dd($user->transactions[0]->id);
}
```

**Model**

```
    public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Transactions', 'user_id');
}
```

It is working for me but i dont want to use `$user->transactions[0]->id`.
How can I fix it?

I know that I can use `hasOne` instead of `hasMany`

```
    public function latest_transaction()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Transactions', 'user_id')->                    
                                       whereStatus('approved')->latest();
}
```

But I want to know every possible solution for it.

Comment: are you want to get first record id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand you want to get latest_transaction id from collection, you can get it using collection methods.

hasOne relation. this will return a collection

```
public function latest_transaction()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Transactions', 'user_id')->whereStatus('approved')->first();
}
```

this method will bring to us transaction id

```
public function get_trans_id(){
    return $this->latest_transaction->id;
}
```

then we will be able to get transaction id using above method

```
$user->get_trans_id(); // 135
```

Comment: No, i dont understand why `$q->where('status', 'approved')->latest()->first()` still return me array
but i want to avoid to use any collection methods, so just use it like that `$user->transactions`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pluck()`  if you want to get only id

```
$user->load([
    'transactions' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('status', 'approved')->latest()->pluck('id');
    },
    'latest_membership',
    'billing'
]);
```

if you want to get more columns

```
$user->load([
    'transactions' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('status', 'approved')->latest()->pluck('id','name',//etc);
    },
    'latest_membership',
    'billing'
]);
```

Comment: it is not what i want, i need to full transaction object, not only 'id', added it only for example

Comment: You can concate columns in pluck()